# how to pass widget dimensions to __init__

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

Apologies if this question has an obvious answer but I have been unable to find a solution for some time now. A widget in my app has a 'graph' that is defined in terms of the widget's dimensions. I can dynamically update the 'graph' from kv because I have access to the widget's dimensions there. However I would like to define a default 'graph', also in terms of the widget's size, that appears at startup. I do not know how to pass the widget's dimensions to the __init__ function. Here is my boiled down example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.9.2
<MainWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_x: 20
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ToggleButton:
            text: 'WF1'
            state: 'down'
            allow_no_selection: False
            on_press:
                root.line_points = [waveform.x, waveform.top, waveform.right, waveform.y]
                root.event_handler()
            group: 'lhs_buttons'
        ToggleButton:
            text: 'WF2'
            allow_no_selection: False
            on_press:
                root.line_points = [waveform.x, waveform.y, waveform.right, waveform.top]
                root.event_handler()
            group: 'lhs_buttons'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_x: 80
        Button:
            id: waveform
            canvas:
                Line:
                    points: root.line_points

''')

class MainWidget(BoxLayout):
    line_points = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #self.line_points =  [waveform.x, waveform.top, waveform.right, waveform.y]  

    def event_handler(self):
        print "event"

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I suppose a partial solution would be to trigger the on_press event in __init__ for one of the buttons , but I have been unable to figure out how to do that. I am new to Python and to Kivy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach will be to bind line_points like this:

```
<MainWidget>:
    line_points: self.calc_line_points(waveform.x, waveform.y, waveform.right, waveform.top)
    ...
```

And **calc_line_points** will be defined such as :

```
    def calc_line_points(self, x, y, right, top):
        return [ x, top, right, y] #put more logic here ...
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly and somehow achieves the desired effect of initialising outside of \__init__. Calc_line_points() is in fact init_line_points() since it executes only once at the start? I realise now that initialising like this (or somehow in \__init__) means that the graphical content is no longer defined in kv section only. In this respect it would be more elegant to trigger the on_press event for one of the buttons. Is that possible? I would be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: @EugeneB - You can put this logic in the kv file using line_points: (x,y) if root.some_val else (y,x), then you should update some_val whever you want. also make some_val a property so changes to it will cause a rendering event

Comment: Thank you again , Yoav, this works and scales to more outcomes by nesting if.. else expressions. Kivy documentation states that this kind of statement - assigning an expression to a property in kv - can only span a single line and 'cannot be extended to multiple lines using newline escaping'. So it becomes messy when there are multiple outcomes and elaborate waveforms. By contrast, multi-line statements that escape their newline are allowed after 'on_press:' statement - better for readibility and maintainability.

Comment: I have done it also via the 'trigger_action' route, by linking an object property declared in MainWidget() to the button's id in kv. Then in \__init__ i can schedule the simulated button press with Clock.schedule_once(self.<objpropname>.trigger_action, 2). Strangely, setting delta-time to 0 or 1 did not work though, not sure why. The same method - linking an object property to a widget id in kv - also works for passing widget's dimensions to python.